# Running sum of elements in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list such that:

```
list =[['x',1,2,3],['y',2,5,4],['z',6,2,1]...]
```

How do I make a running sum and replace specific elements of a list of list, so that:

```
>>>list =[['x',1,2,3],['y',3,7,7],['z',9,9,8]...]
```

> EDIT:
>
> Curious why the disapproval?! Update: I tried @Sunitha solution but
>   accumulate is not in itertools - maybe because running 2.7. I also came up with:

```
    temp = [0,0,0]
    for i, item in enumerate(list):
        temp = [temp[0]+item[1], temp[1]+item[2],temp[2] + item[3]]
        list[i] = [item[0],temp[0],temp[1],temp[2]]
```

> Its clunky, but whatever, I am a biologist. Open to more pythonian
>   answers!

Comment: Would you be open to using a 3rd party library like numpy or pandas?

Comment: Yes for sure if the solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple **one-liner**

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> ll=[['x',1,2,3],['y',2,5,4],['z',6,2,1]]
>>>
>>> list(accumulate(ll, lambda *l: [l[-1][0]] + [sum(r) for r in list(zip(*l))[1:]]))
[['x', 1, 2, 3], ['y', 3, 7, 7], ['z', 9, 9, 8]]
```

**Explanation**

The bulk of the work is done by `accumulate(ll, func)` code, which runs `func` for each element of the iterable `ll`, with the previously computed result. We just have to impelement the function `func` that would do the needful

Consider, the first 2 elements of the list

```
>>> l1=ll[0]; l2=ll[1]
>>> 
>>> l1
['x', 1, 2, 3]
>>> l2
['y', 2, 5, 4]

>>> # A simple zip would create pairs of elements from l1 and l2
>>> f = lambda *l: [list(zip(*l))]
>>> f(l1, l2)
[[('x', 'y'), (1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 4)]]
>>> 
>>> # Remove the first element, so we can calc sum
>>> f = lambda *l: [list(zip(*l))[1:]]
>>> f(l1, l2)
[[(1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 4)]]
>>> 
>>> # Calculate sum for the pairs
>>> f = lambda *l: [sum(r) for r in list(zip(*l))[1:]]
>>> f(l1, l2)
[3, 7, 7]
>>> 
>>> # Now add back the removed first element, but only once
>>> f = lambda *l: [l[-1][0]] + [sum(r) for r in list(zip(*l))[1:]]
>>> f(l1, l2)
['y', 3, 7, 7]
```

Thats it. Now feed this function to accumulate

```
>>> list(accumulate(ll, f))
[['x', 1, 2, 3], ['y', 3, 7, 7], ['z', 9, 9, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Update: I tried @Sunitha solution but accumulate is not in itertools - maybe because running 2.7.

I've tested this code with Python 2.7.15 and Python 3.6.5. This code starts at the second sublist in the list (index 1, if applicable) and looks backwards at the previous sublist to accumulate the values as in your example.

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hmm = [['x', 1, 2, 3], ['y', 2, 5, 4], ['z', 6, 2, 1]]
>>> for i in range(1, len(hmm)):
...     prev = hmm[i - 1][1:]
...     current = iter(hmm[i])
...     hmm[i] = [next(current)] + [a + b for a, b in zip(prev, current)]
... 
>>> hmm
[['x', 1, 2, 3], ['y', 3, 7, 7], ['z', 9, 9, 8]]
```

It could be written slightly different in Python 3 as well:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jun 14 2018, 13:19:33) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hmm = [['x', 1, 2, 3], ['y', 2, 5, 4], ['z', 6, 2, 1]]
>>> for i in range(1, len(hmm)):
...     _, *prev = hmm[i - 1]
...     letter, *current = hmm[i]
...     hmm[i] = [letter] + [a + b for a, b in zip(prev, current)]
... 
>>> hmm
[['x', 1, 2, 3], ['y', 3, 7, 7], ['z', 9, 9, 8]]
```